# Understanding the Client's Responsibilities in OAuth 2.0

Tags: django, angular, oauth, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to learn the inner workings of OAuth 2.0 in my own RESTful app, and I can't seem to find any good explanation of how my Javascript client handles the process.

At this point, I have the client (an Angular 2 SPA) ask the user for their username and password (running Django Rest Framework along with Django Oauth Toolkit). The client makes an AJAX post to the server (specifically to /o/token), and using the resource owner password credentials flow is authenticated and receives the response with the token.

Now, assuming I'm doing everything correctly up to this point, I'm unsure how to properly handle the token from that point forward.

At this point, I'm having my Angular app save the token in a variable and attach the authorization header (with the token) to the calls made to the API. This works as far as granting the correct permissions, but im having a hard time understanding how to maintain persistence of the header (so if the user navigates to a different page, the token is still callable). Initially I stored it in a cookie, but I have concerns with security.

So, first, am I understanding all this correctly? What kind of security concerns should I take into account here? And, of course, how can I save the token on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to store access tokens as user session data because they should be persistent. For example if user leaves your site and then reopens he expects to see himself logged in.

It will be better if you make your sessions server-side: user-agent will store only session ID and all user data will be in your database. User don't need his access token, only your application does.

[Instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions) for implementation of server-side sessions for Django look pretty simple:

> If you want to use a database-backed session, you need to add `'django.contrib.sessions'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.
>
> Once you have configured your installation, run `manage.py migrate` to install the single database table that stores session data.